# IIS url-rewrite only where url has sub-folder

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I need to create a URL re-write/redirect rule in IIS that should only redirect requests that are for the home page of the site. Pages that are in sub-folders should not be redirected (we are rewriting to a different URL for mobile devices to a mobile specific site, but only for the home page. Sub-folders still need to go to the desktop version of the site.)

For example:
http://my.site.com or my.site.com should redirect
http://my.site.com/pages/page1.aspx and my.site.com/pages/page2.aspx should not

I have tried variations on just looking for a url that contains a '/', which work, but then if the url contains 'http://' it still matches the rule.

Answer (score 0):

This rule will redirect **only** homepage to `/pages/page1.aspx`

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect home to /pages/page1.aspx" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/pages/page1.aspx" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of this regex ^$ ?

Comment: that means `empty string` what is equal to the homepage